# media player get duration is not incorrect value for .ogg audio files

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, ogg

I made an app.There are two scenarios in my app:

**1) for Mp3 Files**

I am playing .mp3 songs through the media player. When I retrieve the total duration and current duration, it works perfectly and gives me correct values. 
This is the code I am using:

```
long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

**2) For Ogg Files**

I am also playing .ogg audio format songs through the media player. When I retrieve the total duration and current duration, it is **NOT** working perfectly - it gives me the wrong total duration of media player.

**Example**
Below I am attaching the screen capture of the wrong total duration of the .ogg file. Hope you can look at the bottom of the image highlighted in red.

**Total duration is greater than the current position.**

[image]
Thanks in advance if you solve my problem.

Comment: `not incorrect` means `not not correct`, which means just `correct`